# Why is my buttons stacking top-bottom not side by side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, single-page-application

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ikah.jpg)

Currently, my buttons are placed top bottom, and whenever I add a button, the button stacks from the bottom.

However, I want to stack it side by side, and 3 rows of four columns, like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y11yk.jpg)

This problem occured when I changed this website which was in MPA to SPA (for a school project).

```
  // Function to load the blade choice view
  function loadBladeChoiceView() {
    const app = document.getElementById("app");
    app.innerHTML = `
      <center><header style="margin-top: 50px;"><h1>Blades</h1></header></center>
      <div class="toolbar">
        <button class="toolbar-button" id="all">All</button>
        <button class="toolbar-button" id="butterfly">Butterfly</button>
        <button class="toolbar-button" id="dhs">DHS</button>
        <button class="toolbar-button" id="nittaku">Nittaku</button>
        <button class="toolbar-button" id="xiom">Xiom</button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <button class="returnhome"><span>Home</span></button>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button class="btn-choicebutton" data-brand="butterfly" id="fzdalc" style="background-image: url('https://takkuzone.com/web/product/big/202208/b46a6ff1e142fdad9e4d9b5338a133d9.png');">
          <span>FZD ALC<br>Weight ~87g Price: $166.49</span>
          <div class="text-box">Fan Zhendong ALC</div>
        </button>
        <button class="btn-choicebutton" data-brand="butterfly" id="fzdzlc" style="background-image: url('https://shop.butterflyonline.com/Item%20Images/1262.media.01.jpg?resizeid=5&resizeh=1200&resizew=1200');">
          <span>FZD ZLC<br>Weight ~86g Price: $242.99</span>
          <div class="text-box">Fan Zhendong ZLC</div>
        </button>
      </div>
    `;
```

This is how I have the js in the SPA website, and the css for the corresponding problem is:
`

```
.btn-choicebutton {
  background: no-repeat center top; /* Adjusted to 'center top' */
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px; /* Increased height to accommodate text box */
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.btn-choicebutton span {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.btn-choicebutton:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.btn-choicebutton:hover span {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.button-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /* 4 columns */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);    /* 3 rows */
  grid-gap: 20px; /* Spacing between buttons */
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: If you're adding new buttons to the grid, you've to modify `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` values accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your button-container css property like this.

```css
    .button-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

By setting grid-auto-rows to minmax(0, 1fr), you allow the rows to automatically adjust their height based on content, ensuring that the buttons stack side by side in 3 rows and 4 columns.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to copy nd paste it in. Now I edited the post. But I did try that display:flex; and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I copy and pasted the code you gave me, but it still doesn't seem to work.